# Laravel Markdown - What is the difference between Str::markdown($string), and GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Markdown, and spatie/laravel-markdown libraries

Tags: php, laravel, markdown

I'm new to PHP Markdown.

Please correct me if I'm using terminology wrong.

I have a textarea input which value I'd like to save to database and later present on my page.

I need simple HTML elements like `h1`, `h2`, `p`, `a`, `ol`, `li`.

I assume I'd like to use the [markdown notation](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/).

So, I save this sample text to my database:

```
This is a [sample](text). <script>alert('hohoho')</script>
```

And I can render it with using `{!! Str::markdown($string) !!}`

as

```
<a href="text">sample</a><script>alert('hohoho')</script>
```

which seems fine. The script is not executed.

Is this safe?

"safe" in a way a user can't input anything into the database through standard Laravel app that could be used maliciously. E.g. `<script>alert('aa')</script>` or `<?= 'bb' ?>`. Please do point out if I'm missing anything?

What is the difference (in general and in my case) when using `Str::markdown()` and any of the following libraries:

[GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Markdown](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Markdown)

[spatie/laravel-markdown](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-markdown)

Comment: That depends on a lot of things: how do you define "safe"? And how do to persist the data?

Comment: "safe" would mean the user can't input anything into the database through standard Laravel app that could be used maliciously. E.g. `<script>alert('aa')</script>` or `<?= 'bb' ?>`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: There you are..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three implementations are thin wrappers around `league/commonmark`, so they should work more or less identically.

Comment: You mean `raw()` on the query? No, I'm not doing that. I saw that `Str::markdown()` ends up in the `league/commonmark` library but wanted to double check as both of the libraries have quite a bit of starts on github so I'm confused what's that about since `Str::markdown()` offers similar functionality (same in my case). I suppose there are more to this than what I'm using it for. Thanks!